# Get current date as String warning deprecated toGmtString() issue

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, android-date

I want to get the current date day/month/year min:sec in Android so I have used the follow code

```
String data="";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
data=c.getTime().toGMTString();
```

But Eclipse notify me that the method `.toGMTString();` is deprecated.

How could I get the current date as formatted String avoiding the use of this deprecated method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Android documentation:

> This method is deprecated.
>   use [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Since the GMT string is represented as `22 Jun 1999 13:02:00 GMT`, we can use `SimpleDateFormat` (subclass of the abstract `DateFormat`) like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String asGmt = df.format(c.getTime()) + " GMT";
```

<s>Might want to double-check that format, but this'll get you started.</s> Have a look at [this IDEOne code](http://ideone.com/8y5xn).

Answer (score 5):

The method `toGMTString()` from the type Date is deprecated.

you can check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for different types of date formations.

In your case use

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String data="";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
data=dfDate.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(data);//==========> 17/Oct/2012 08:36:52
```

If you want to print month number instead of month name

use

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String data="";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
data=dfDate.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(data);//==========> 17/10/2012 08:36:52
```